# Gunicorn Django cannot find wsgi module

Tags: python, django, deployment, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a Django/Python3 application with Gunicorn. Everyone agrees that this is easy, but deploying web applications seems extremely complicated to me, having been raised on Java/Tomcat apps.

So I installed Gunicorn:

```
$ sudo pip3 install gunicorn
```

I navigated to the directory with the `./manage.py` file and execute:

```
$ gunicorn my_project/wsgi:application
```

and I get a traceback, the gist of which is:

```
ImportError: No module named 'my_project/wsgi'
```

My `wsgi.py` file is exactly as Django generated it, and is located at `my_project/wsgi.py`:

```
"""
WSGI config for titlematch_api project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "titlematch_api.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am using Python 3, Django 1.8, and gunicorn 19.3.0

I was able to get gunicorn to run the following test:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    data = b'Hello, World!\n'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type','text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried with and without a virtualenv.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application
```

It is meant to be a module path, not a file system path.

Comment: +1, thanks. I've tried to accept this answer twice, but received an error both times, please accept my gratitude.